# How do I get the values of RawAttributes

Tags: powershell, iis

I have a powershell script that is checking IIS config

```
$httpProtocolPath = "system.webServer/httpProtocol"      

$foo = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath  $httpProtocolPath | Get-IISConfigCollection -CollectionName "customHeaders"
```

inspecting $foo is looks like this:
[image]

I need some help as to how to check or at least get the `RawAttibutes` into some variables so I can check them.

Thx

[UPDATE]

this is now working thanks to Answer from @Tomek:

```
 $httpProtocolPath = "system.webServer/httpProtocol"
 $httpProtocolSection = $Configuration.GetSection($httpProtocolPath)


   $customHeadersCollection = $httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders")
    $customHeader = $customHeadersCollection | select rawattributes | select -ExpandProperty * | Where-Object {
                            $name = $_ | Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -AttributeName "name"
                            $value = $_ | Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -AttributeName "value"
                            ($name -eq "StrictTransport-Security") #-and ([int]$value -gt 0) 
                    }
```

Comment: `$foo.RawAttributes`?

Comment: `$foo = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath  $httpProtocolPath | Get-IISConfigCollection -CollectionName "customHeaders" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RawAttributes`?

Comment: @Paxz - that returns an empty string or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wan to see what data type is  RawAttributes. Normally to figure it out I'd use Show-Object command 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/26/spelunking-with-show-object/

As for this exact case  - this worked well for me

```
$foo|select rawattributes|select -ExpandProperty *
```

Comment: Thats not really explaining how to get the value of a subelement, which is the actuall question.

Comment: Hey - Using show object You can explore it easily and see how to find and return the property You are interested in. That's my input on this. Since I do not have such object to test and Your idea returns an empty string I'd thing it's worth to see how the actual object looks like:)

Comment: What I meant was, that proposals and tipps shouldn't be posted as answers when they don't offer a concrete solution. This should be rather be a comment on the question than an answer.

Comment: ouch, You are right. I did not ment to post it as answer, just a comment ,

Comment: i updated my questions with the final code that used this double select idea - thanks!