# Find the http response headers for IIS using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, http-headers

I want to find the custom headers for a particular site.

I am able to view the raw attributes using the below command. I think this is global value for all sites. I have created some headers for some sites. But I am not able to view it. Is there a command to view for a particular site.

```
>Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath system.webServer/httpProtocol | Get-IISConfigCollection -CollectionName "customHeaders"

Attributes      : {name, value}
ChildElements   : {}
ElementTagName  : add
IsLocallyStored : True
Methods         : 
RawAttributes   : {[name, X-Powered-By], [value, ASP.NET]}
Schema          : Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to find using the below command.

```
> Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath system.webServer/httpProtocol -CommitPath "testsite" | Get-IISConfigCollection -CollectionName "customHeaders"
```

But I am not able to extract the name and value.
I used `select-object rawattribute`, but it gives empty {}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get-Website command to get the configuration information of a specific website:

```
Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site"
```

This command will return the configuration information of the default website.

Comment: I tried as : Get-Website -Name "testsite"|  Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath system.webServer/httpProtocol | Get-IISConfigCollection -CollectionName "customHeaders".    But I get error as : Get-IISConfigSection : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: the above command doesnt give the http response header.  (system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders)

Comment: You can try to use "httpProtocolSection.GetCollection" command, There is a similar question in this link you can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175529/get-iis-http-response-headers-using-powershell-rawattributes

Comment: yes, that is the command I used (in the question above). The problem is I want it for a particular site - eg: testsite.The output is for general sites.

Comment: You can try to use "Get-IisHttpHeader -SiteName SopwithCamel", this command will returns the HTTP headers for the SopwithCamel website. Carbon is a PowerShell module for automating the configuration Windows 7, 8, 2008, and 2012 and automation the installation and configuration of Windows applications, websites, and services. For more information about Carbon, you can refer to this link: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Carbon/2.7.0